# Shapeless, how to prove Nat is within Sized boundaries?

Tags: scala, shapeless

We have two entities: one our hash is a number, it is represented by a `Nat`, and another is the sized vector. We want that our hash number belong to one of the elements of the sized vector. Normally we would compute a desired index with mod `nat % size`.

```scala
class SizedVector[A, L <: Nat: ToInt](s: Sized[Vector[A], L]) {
  def shard[Hash <: Nat: ToInt, Index <: Nat](
    hash: Hash32[Hash]
  )(
    implicit
    mod: Mod.Aux[Hash, L, Index],
    index: ToInt[Index]
  ): A = s.at[Index]
}
```

How can we prove that the result of the mod `Index` at the type-level is within the length of the sized vector? Currently the compiler would tell you

```
could not find implicit value for parameter diff: shapeless.ops.nat.Diff[L,shapeless.Succ[Index]]
): A = s.at[Index]
```

Assuming it has no idea what is the difference between the vector length and the computed index.

Is it possible to ensure the safe access and make it total this way?

Scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/kubum/AmbBX3rwQfyXjqRrglYyIg/5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If compiler lacks some implicit you add it as a parameter. Try

```
def shard[Hash <: Nat: ToInt, Index <: Nat](
  hash: Hash32[Hash]
)(
  implicit
  mod: Mod.Aux[Hash, L, Index],
  index: ToInt[Index],
  diff: Diff[L, Succ[Index]]
): A = s.at[Index]
```

Comment: Ah, thank you, Dmytro, fantastic! I am not sure why I only tried to do it with `Aux` before. This works well, I wonder what are the steps when you abstract it away, https://scastie.scala-lang.org/kubum/AmbBX3rwQfyXjqRrglYyIg/10?

Comment: With `Aux` this should also work: `def shard[Hash <: Nat: ToInt, Index <: Nat, Out <: Nat](
                                                 hash: Hash32[Hash]
                                               )(
                                                 implicit
                                                 mod: Mod.Aux[Hash, L, Index],
                                                 index: ToInt[Index],
                                                 diff: Diff.Aux[L, Succ[Index], Out]
                                               ): A = s.at[Index]`

Comment: @kubum Once again, if compiler lacks some implicits you add them as parameters. `class Container[TotalBuckets <: Nat: ToInt, Index <: Nat](implicit
                                                            mod: Mod.Aux[_13, TotalBuckets, Index],
                                                            diff: Diff[TotalBuckets, Succ[Index]],
                                                            index: ToInt[Index])...` `new Container[_5, _3]`

Comment: @kubum If you want to hide second type parameter `_3` you can try "partial application" trick or creating custom type class https://stackoverflow.com/a/55236130/5249621 https://stackoverflow.com/a/55637495/5249621

Comment: I see your idea, @dmytro-mitin. Thank you. One last moment, does it mean the `Nats` cannot come from the inside of the `Container`? Now it is a total function, it accepts any nats and gives an element back. How do people encode it without hardcoding the index into the constructor? *UPD:* I see you commented! Thanks!